# use input from combo box as integer in code (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

right now my code reads

```
Dim divisor as Integer = "10"
```

i have created a form with a drop-down combo box that allows a user to choose the divisor instead of it being hardwired into the code. the name of the combo box is 'divisor1'

how do i refer to the input in divisor1 to be read as the divisor? i.e.

```
Dim divisor as Integer = divisor1 'throws an error
```

TIA

Comment: `"10"` is a string and not an integer. `10` is. Also: refer to the correct property of the `divisor1` combobox.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to use a property on the `divisor1` combo box, not the box itself.  But in order to use it as an integer, you need to convert it from a string.  Which should also come with some error checking, just in case the input isn't actually an integer.  Something like this:

```
Dim divisor as Int32 = 1
If Int32.TryParse(divisor1.Text, divisor) Then
    ' Perform your logic
Else
    ' The input wasn't a valid integer, maybe show an error?
End If
```

What this does is initialize a default integer as 1 (normally the default might be 0, but if you're looking to *divide by* this number then perhaps 0 isn't the best idea), then it tries to parse the value of `divisor1.Text` into that integer.  If it succeeds, you can continue with your code.  If it fails, then the combo box didn't have a valid number.

Comment: i am not sure i get that ... somewhere else in the code the divisor is called for. all i want to do is instead of having the number hard coded ("10") i want to read the number selected by the user from the combo box. so instead of dim divisor as integer = "10" i want it to say dim divisor as integer = [the number selected in the combo box called divisor1]

Comment: @user2258973: Without knowing more about your code, I can't really advise on "somewhere else."  In this example `divisor` holds the numeric representation of the value from the combo box.  You can use that value anywhere you need to.

Comment: you might be better off with a numericupdown control